# Insert new data automatically between two lines, concurrently

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, concurrency

I have a Google Sheet and many users that can run a script to add a line into it (in the second line, to be precise, under the title of the columns).

I could use locks, ok. But I'm wondering that for **such a simple request: "Insert this data at that line"**, do I really need to use the lock mechanism?

I use this syntax:

```
sheet.insertRowBefore(2).getRange(2, 1, 1, 5).setValues([['Sam','Jack','Bill','John','Joe']]);
```

This line of code performs 2 operations:
A. Add a new line at LINE2
B. Edit the LINE2 with the user's values.

The problem is that when two users X and Y execute the script concurrently, it may happens that:

1. User X performs A (create a new line at the "LINE2", shifting the others)
2. User Y performs A (create a new line at the "LINE2", shifting the others)
3. User X performs B (insert X data in "LINE2" line)
4. User Y performs B (insert Y data in "LINE2" line)

The WRONG result is:

```
- LINE2: data of Y
- LINE3: empty
```

The RIGHT result should be:

```
- LINE2: data of Y
- LINE3: data of X
```

Thank you

Comment: If you have concurrent script executions with side effects (writing to a sheet), I think locks is the simplest solution.  You could also store the records and their "created datetime" in an intermediary sheet periodically pushing them to the main sheet.  However, it is more complex than locks.